# Attribute Error: module 'uctypes' has no attribute 'INT32'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

When I try to run `rcReceiver_IBUS.py`, I am getting this error:

```
module 'uctypes' has no attribute 'INT32'  

timer.py line 17

Your program tries to access attribute INT32 of an object of type 'uctypes', but this type doesn't have such attribute.
```

.

**rcReceiver_IBUS.py**

```
from machine import UART
import time
buffer=bytearray(31) 
uart = UART(1, 115200) # uart1 tx-pin 4, rx-pin 5
while True:
    c=uart.read(1)
    if c[0] == 0x20:
        uart.readinto(buffer)
        checksum = 0xffff - 0x20
        for i in range(29): checksum -= buffer[i]
        if checksum == (buffer[30] << 8) | buffer[29]:
            # skip buffer[0] = 0x40
            ch1 = buffer[2]*255+buffer[1]
            ch2 = buffer[4]*255+buffer[3]
            ch3 = buffer[6]*255+buffer[5]
            ch4 = buffer[8]*255+buffer[7]
            ch5 = buffer[10]*255+buffer[9]
            ch6 = buffer[12]*255+buffer[11]
            print('ch  1-',ch1,'  2-',ch2,'  3-',ch3,'  4-',ch4,'  5-',ch5,'   6-',ch6)
```

.

**timer.py**

```
import ffilib
import uctypes
import array
import uos
import os
import utime
from signal import *

libc = ffilib.libc()
librt = ffilib.open("librt")

CLOCK_REALTIME = 0
CLOCK_MONOTONIC = 1
SIGEV_SIGNAL = 0

sigval_t = {
    "sival_int": uctypes.INT32 | 0,
    "sival_ptr": (uctypes.PTR | 0, uctypes.UINT8),
}

sigevent_t = {
    "sigev_value": (0, sigval_t),
    "sigev_signo": uctypes.INT32 | 8,
    "sigev_notify": uctypes.INT32 | 12,
}

timespec_t = {
    "tv_sec": uctypes.INT32 | 0,
    "tv_nsec": uctypes.INT64 | 8,
}

itimerspec_t = {
    "it_interval": (0, timespec_t),
    "it_value": (16, timespec_t),
}


__libc_current_sigrtmin = libc.func("i", "__libc_current_sigrtmin", "")
SIGRTMIN = __libc_current_sigrtmin()

timer_create_ = librt.func("i", "timer_create", "ipp")
timer_settime_ = librt.func("i", "timer_settime", "PiPp")

def new(sdesc):
    buf = bytearray(uctypes.sizeof(sdesc))
    s = uctypes.struct(uctypes.addressof(buf), sdesc, uctypes.NATIVE)
    return s

def timer_create(sig_id):
    sev = new(sigevent_t)
    #print(sev)
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGRTMIN + sig_id
    timerid = array.array('P', [0])
    r = timer_create_(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, sev, timerid)
    os.check_error(r)
    #print("timerid", hex(timerid[0]))
    return timerid[0]

def timer_settime(tid, hz):
    period = 1000000000 // hz
    new_val = new(itimerspec_t)
    new_val.it_value.tv_nsec = period
    new_val.it_interval.tv_nsec = period
    #print("new_val:", bytes(new_val))
    old_val = new(itimerspec_t)
    #print(new_val, old_val)
    r = timer_settime_(tid, 0, new_val, old_val)
    os.check_error(r)
    #print("old_val:", bytes(old_val))
    #print("timer_settime", r)


class Timer:

    def __init__(self, id, freq):
        self.id = id
        self.tid = timer_create(id)
        self.freq = freq

    def callback(self, cb):
        self.cb = cb
        timer_settime(self.tid, self.freq)
        org_sig = signal(SIGRTMIN + self.id, self.handler)
        #print("Sig %d: %s" % (SIGRTMIN + self.id, org_sig))

    def handler(self, signum):
        #print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
        self.cb(self)
```

But when I open `uctypes.py`, `INT32` is in the file. It seems there is no problem in file. What am I missing?

.

**uctypes.py**

```
ARRAY = -1073741824
BFINT16 = -671088640
BFINT32 = -402653184
BFINT8 = -939524096
BFUINT16 = -805306368
BFUINT32 = -536870912
BFUINT8 = -1073741824
BF_LEN = 22
BF_POS = 17
BIG_ENDIAN = 1
FLOAT32 = -268435456
FLOAT64 = -134217728
INT16 = 402653184
INT32 = 671088640
INT64 = 939524096
INT8 = 134217728
LITTLE_ENDIAN = 0
NATIVE = 2
PTR = 536870912
UINT16 = 268435456
UINT32 = 536870912
UINT64 = 805306368
UINT8 = 0
VOID = 0


def addressof():
    pass


def bytearray_at():
    pass


def bytes_at():
    pass


def sizeof():
    pass


class struct:
    ""
```

Comment: Please include code and errors as text and not as images.

Comment: The output of the `locate` command shows that there is more than one `uctypes.py` file on your system.  You must be importing the wrong one.  Show us the value of `uctypes.__file__`

Comment: @JohnGordon both of the uctypes.py files have INT32. I checked both of them.

Comment: What is the value of `uctypes.__file__`?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @JohnGordonHow can I show value of uctypes.__file__ ?

Comment: @martineau I removed images. I changed them with codes.

Comment: @ewong I removed images. I changed them with codes.

Comment: Your code looks OK, so if there wasn't an `import` error, then you must be importing a different file with the same name. Do a `print(uctypes.__file__)` after the import to see the file path of the module so you can verify it's the right one (as @JohnGordon suggested previously).

Comment: @martineau  It helped and solved. Thank you. Wrong file path.